# Methods on an object created via composition can't access all properties

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, object-composition

I'm building the concept of a family for a product, with members being of different types (`accountHolder`, `payingCustomer`, `student`, and so on). Originally I built these as sub-classes of `FamilyMember`, but I ended up with some repeated code and eventually bumped into a significant problem: a `student` of our platform can also be the sole `payingCustomer` and `accountHolder`.

Given how object composition is widely touted as a good idea in JS, I decided to go that route. However, the methods of a particular object type (e.g. `accountHolder`) can't access properties of the instantiated object, if the property belong to another object type (e.g. `student`).

To make this more objective I've decided to replicate the behaviour using the following code:

```
const person = (props) => {
  let state = {
    name: props.name,
  }

  state.isOfAge = () => {
    // state.isAdult is always undefined because
    // isAdult doesn't exist in this object
    return state.isAdult === true
  }

  return state
}

const adult = (props) => {
  return {
    isAdult: true,
  }
}

const factory = (props) => {
  return Object.assign({}, person(props), adult(props))
}

const john = factory({
  name: 'John',
})

console.clear()
console.log(john) // { isAdult: true, name: "John", isOfAge... }
console.log(john.isOfAge()) // false
```

I was expecting `john`'s method `isOfAge` to be able to access the property `isAdult`, since it's in the object. However, conceptually I understand why it doesn't work: `isOfAge` is a method of `state`, not the resulting `adult` instance.

If I were using classes or even a traditional prototype/constructor mechanism I knew how to make it work (e.g. attaching to `prototype`). With object composition I've no idea how to get there, probably due to lacking experience with FP.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `this` instead of `state` inside `isOfAge`. That way, the `this` will be deduces when the method `isOfAge` gets called, it will be bound to whatever object it is called on. Though, you'll have to use a regular function instead of an arrow one for that to work (arrow functions don't have a `this`):

```js
const person = (props) => {
  let state = {
    name: props.name,
  }

  state.isOfAge = function() {       // use a regular function
    return this.isAdult === true     // use this here instead of state
  }

  return state
}

const adult = (props) => {
  return {
    isAdult: true,
  }
}

const factory = (props) => {
  return Object.assign({}, person(props), adult(props))
}

const john = factory({
  name: 'John',
})

console.log(john);
console.log(john.isOfAge());         // returns 'true' because 'this' inside 'isOfAge' will be 'john'
```

Comment: perfect, was just about to mention about the arrow function there :)

Comment: I can't believe I was this stupid, I forgot arrow functions lexically bind their context!

Comment: @FilipeCatraia It happens. :-)

Answer (score 1):

## Object Composition

> - *All objects made from other objects and language primitives are composite objects.*
> - The act of creating a composite object is known as composition.
>
>   **...**
> - Concatenation composes objects by extending an existing object with new properties, e.g., `Object.assign(destination, a, b), {...a, ...b}`.
>
>   **...**
>                         
>   <sup>*[The Hidden Treasures of Object Composition](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/the-hidden-treasures-of-object-composition-60cd89480381#dc91)*</sup>

---

So from your pattern and use of a [factory function](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-factory-functions-with-es6-4d224591a8b1) it looks like concatenation? The demo below is a concatenation composition. Note the parenthesis wrapped around the brackets of `payment`:

> ```
> const payment = (status) => ({...})
> ```

this allows `payment` to be returned as an object instead of a function. If you have data that's a little more flexible, you'll need less methods. `name: string` and `age: number` are the properties I used considering it practical or in your case `name: string` and `adult: boolean`.

---

### Demo

```js
const payment = (status) => ({
  adult: () => status.age > 17 ? true : false,
  account: () => status.adult() ? 'holder' : 'student'
});

const member = (name, age) => {
  let status = {
    name,
    age
  };
  return Object.assign(status, payment(status));
};

const soze = member('Kaiser Soze', 57);
console.log(soze);
console.log(soze.adult());
console.log(soze.account());

const jr = member('Kaiser Soze Jr.', 13);
console.log(jr);
console.log(jr.adult());
console.log(jr.account());
```

Comment: Thank you @zer00ne, your answer does a very good job of contrasting with concatenation. I accepted the other response as simply avoiding an arrow function and using `this` solves my particular issue, but generally you're as correct. Cheers <3